# Javascript Confirm Method is not working, Why there is no action on calling the method?

Tags: javascript, html

I have got stuck to this small thing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function cnfm(){
   var r = window.confirm("hey");
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="cnfm">here</button>
 </body>

</html>
```

Whenever I am pressing on the button, no action.

Comment: you have to execute the function `onclick="cnfm()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call your method with paranthesis, `<button onclick="cnfm()">here</button>`

Answer (score 0):

try for best practice and clean code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>
  <button id='btn'>here</button>


  <script>
    let btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
   
    btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      let r = window.confirm("hey");
    })

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is modern javascript. now your confirm work. if user click of OK then r is equal true and if click on CANCEL thats be false.